# Importing a schema in Oracle with a different name

Tags: oracle

I exported an Oracle XE 18c database with:

```
expdp USER1/pwd DIRECTORY=backups DUMPFILE=file.dmp 
      LOGFILE=config_export.log SCHEMAS=USER1
```

Now, I created in a different machine another user and schema USER2, and need to import all the tables from USER1 in USER2.

In the second machine, I import with:

```
impdp USER2/pwd DIRECTORY=backups DUMPFILE=file.DMP 
      SCHEMAS=USER1 TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE LOGFILE=config_import.log
```

But I get the error that USER1 does not exist. Is there a way to import the schema without creating USER1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[REMAP_SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523)

> The Data Pump Import command-line mode REMAP_SCHEMA parameter loads
>   all objects from the source schema into a target schema.
>
> Default: There is no default
>
> Purpose
>
> Loads all objects from the source schema into a target schema.

Example:

`remap_schema=USER1:USER2`